# Get users sorted?

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-manager, user-management

Right now we have about 1000 users of our CMS 2013 version. But the users under user management is initially sorted on what seems to be tcm id (creation time). here - you have the option to filter or sort. Is less of a problem.

But the publisher queue, has a filter for User. That is not sorted. The dropdown is very small and you cannot "type" chars to find a person. So you need each time to look at 1000 members to find the user you are looking for. And when you only see 7 names in a random order - you can spend ages trying to find the person you look for.

This is the more annoying feature I have seen. Fine if you have 10 users but after a few hundred.. you spend way to much time trying to find the user you want to find.

Anything that can be done to see it sorted?

Comment: The question is answered here at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273228/tridion-2011-how-to-sort-user-list-on-publishing-queue

Comment: That's awkward. A duplicate of a question on SO. What do we do? Ask to have that one migrated here?

Comment: You can try asking to move the other one, but the flag option shows `off-topic because… (too old to migrate)`. Technically, this question is for another version and doesn't duplicate the question _within_ Tridion StackExchange. A google search might reveal StackOverflow's duplicate, but I wouldn't be too quick to close this one.

Comment: Btw, with at least two questions preferring this list to be sorted, I recommend voting for [this sorting idea on Tridion Ideas](http://ideas.sdltridion.com/ideas/detail.asp?i=4261) from Frida Polheimer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the answer you want but the only out of the box way for this is to select  `(All)` users and then use the `User` column to sort/filter according to your needs. This is more of an issue if you've 100's of users publishing (as opposed to just in the list)... in which case you're looking at a GUI extension (that I'd certainly love to install and feedback on as it's something that's annoyed me for years!!!)

Comment: I have two partially helpful things to add: browser find ([CTRL+F]) can help find names in that Publishing Queue list (and elsewhere). Oddly, pressing a letter jumps to the first matching item in the user name drop down. Pressing the letter again, however, only seems to cycle through users if they happen to be adjacent to each other.